# Autenticación a Business Central de Dynamics

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, oauth2, azure-aad

Estoy intentando realizar una conexión al servicio de Business Central con los datos de autenticación y me da error. Mientras cuando lo pruebo en Postman, funciona perfectamente.

Me debe estar faltando algo que no estoy viendo y espero que me podáis ayudar.
El código que tengo hasta ahora es el siguiente:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

private void BusinessCentral()
{
    string TenantId = "...";
    string ClientId = "...";
    string ClientSecret = "...";

    string CallbackUrl = @"https://businesscentral.dynamics.com/";
    string GetUrl = string.Format(@"https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/{0}/Production/api/v2.0/companies", TenantId);

    try
    {
        string[] Scopes = new[] { "https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/.default" };
        var App = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(ClientId)
            .WithClientSecret(ClientSecret)
            .WithRedirectUri(CallbackUrl)
            .WithTenantId(TenantId)
            .Build();

        var result = App.AcquireTokenForClient(Scopes).ExecuteAsync().Result;

        if (result != null)
        {

            HttpClient HttpCli = new HttpClient();
            var defaultRequestHeaders = HttpCli.DefaultRequestHeaders;
            if (defaultRequestHeaders.Accept == null || !defaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Any(m => m.MediaType == "application/json"))
            {
                HttpCli.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            }
            defaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", result.CreateAuthorizationHeader());

            HttpResponseMessage response = HttpCli.GetAsync(GetUrl).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var apiResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JObject>>(json);

            }
            else
            {
                string content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                // ERROR: "code": "Authentication_InvalidCredentials", "message":"The server has rejected the client credentials.

            }
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        
    }
}
```

El error que me devuelve es el siguiente:

> {"error":{"code":"Authentication_InvalidCredentials","message":"The server has rejected the client credentials.  CorrelationId:  161ce9f5-f2f7-4f56-ad1e-b5a7a159292e."}}

Enlace de referencia: [Github: active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/5199032b352a912e7cc0fce143f81664ba1a8c26/daemon-console)

Gracias por vuestro apoyo.

Comment: falta informacion, result.CreateAuthorizationHeader() esto por ejemplo que hace?? como es la autenticacion?? basic? oauth?

Comment: El header es "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI...". La autenticación es con OAuth 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código es correcto, el problema era de la configuración del Business Central respecto a permisos.

No dispongo de acceso a esa configuración, por tanto no puedo dar detalles.